# variogram range is not unique within some specific degree

Tags: r, geospatial, covariogram

[variogram of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTjIs.jpg)

I got this variogram from a set of spatial temporal data, but i am wondering why the 90 degree have such a 'small' range compare to other, is it my data problem or I can adjust some setting in the

```
v<-variogram(Thickness~Age+x+y,data,alpha=seq(0,135,45),beta=seq(0,45,45))
```

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: the range of the curve corresponds to the range of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are referring to the range of the plotted graph and not the `range parameter` that is used in Geostatistics.

This is simply, because the longest distance is smaller at 90 degrees. For example, imagine that you have observations in a rectangle with width 100 and height 50. Then, when computing the variagrom, pair of points will be observed at the distance of at most 100 for 0 degrees, while, at most of 50 for 90 degrees.